# Can cocos2d support 4096x4096 texture on Ipad3?

Tags: xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, ipad-3

Ipad1 can only support 2048x2048, so I want to know ipad retina support bigger size texture.
I use cocos2d v1.01

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maximum texture sizes.

iPad 1
iPad 2 < iOS 5.1
**2048 * 2048**

iPad 2 >= iOS 5.1
iPad 3
**4096 * 4096**

via @LearnCocos2D